# "syntax error at or near 'order'"" in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I'm trying to add a column named *order* to my table. I realize that *order* is a reserved word in SQL.  So, how do I do it?
My command:

```
   alter table mytable add column order integer;
```

I've also tried:

```
   alter table mytable add column 'order' integer;
```

PostgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: `'order'`  is a string constant not a column name. See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: *Never* use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifiers. Only use legal, lower-case names in Postgres and live happily ever after (without the need for double-quoting).

Comment: May I suggest "display_order" or "ordinality" as the column name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
alter table mytable add column "order" integer;
```

But, you might want to consider using a non-reserved name instead, like `sort_order` or something similar that reflects what the column is used for (and isn't a reserved word).

Comment: Thanks.  This one worked for me. StackOverflow wants me to wait for 9 minutes before I can resolve this.

Comment: Huh, just realized that it is probably a bad idea to name columns after reserved words...maybe I'll rethink this.

Comment: @user1344643 Indeed it is a bad practice to use reserved keywords - just don't do it and you'll save yourself a lot of headache at some point :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using order which is a reserved keyword you should consider renaming that to something like orders. And the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need "column". Plus "order" is a keyword in SQL, so you should use a different name for your column. Follow this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype
```

Source: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN "order" integer
```