# No qualifying bean of type Error in Junit test

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to connect two different data source using spring boot version 2.0.3. One is pointing to the MySQL and another is PostgreSQL. MySQL passed every test. But problem with the PostgreSQL.

Here is the Entity class that should be mapped to PostgreSQL.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Order {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  private String productName;
}
```

This is the configuration class for PostgreSQL.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackageClasses = Order.class,
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "orderEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "orderTransactionManager"
)
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class OrderConfig {

@Autowired
Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("order.datasource.class"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("order.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("order.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("order.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "orderEntityManager")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(this.getDataSource());
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.seal.multipledatasource.entity.order");

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter);
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("order.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("order.jpa.hibernate.dialect"));
    localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean(name = "orderTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
}
```

Spring Data Repository.

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepo extends JpaRepository<Order, Long>{
}
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = OrderConfig.class)   
public class OrderRepoTest {

@Autowired
private OrderRepo orderRepo;

@Test
@Transactional
public void testOrderRepo() {
    Order order = orderRepo.save(new Order(null, "ACT LITE"));
    Assertions.assertThat(order).isNotNull();
    Assertions.assertThat(order.getId()).isNotZero();
}
}
```

Log File

```
                org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440)
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424)
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315)
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166)
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135)
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121)
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155)
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
            at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
            at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
            at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
            at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
            at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:107)
            at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
            at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
            at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
            at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
            at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
            at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
            at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
            at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
            at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
            at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
            at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
            at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
            Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "order"
            Position: 14
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2178)
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270)
            at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266)
            at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
            ... 57 common frames omitted

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'com.seal.multipledatasource.repo.OrderRepoTest': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'orderRepo'; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'com.seal.multipledatasource.repo.order.OrderRepo' 
available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:401)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.seal.multipledatasource.repo.order.OrderRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
        ... 27 more
```

You can find the full log file [Here[GitHub Gist Link]](https://gist.github.com/muztaba/a2a31b03279cc2219addae0827d0d9e0)

== UPDATE ==

I have tested with the `Order` entity with the MySQL DB. It causes same kind ofo error with Order table

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
```

And also no bean found exception.

Then I renamed the entity class and the SQL error gone. But the no bean found exception still persist for the OrderRepo bean.

Comment: You need not to provide `@Repository` Annotation to your Spring Data Repository (`OrderRepo`), anything that extends `JpaRepository` is automatically a Repository. So if you do it again, two different beans will be created, which will cause this error.

Comment: @MunishChandel That should not be the case. anyway I have tested removing the Repository annotation. It didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen your logs, and it seems that there is a problem with the 'order' keyword:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "order"

Maybe this could help you: [Error: syntax error at or near 'order'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092328/error-syntax-error-at-or-near-order)

UPDATED:

As we've seen in the comments below, the problem raises in a bad scanning of packages. Spring can't find the repository.

You should have

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "com.seal.multipledatasource.repo"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated the post. please take a look at the update portion.

Comment: Have you tried scanning the packages?
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.seal.multipledatasource.repo"})

Spring throws that exception because can't find the OrderRepo anywhere. That happens when the package isn't scanned or the bean wasn't properly declared

Comment: Hey. I figure out the problem from your last comment. I mistakenly refer the Entity class rather than Repository class. That should be like `@EnableJpaRepositories( basePackageClasses = OrderRepo.class,}) `. or as your's `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.seal.multipledatasource.repo"})` Please put that in your answer. I will mark your answer accepted.